# Why don't Kohanim and Levi'im thank Hashem for not making them regular Israelites?

Tags: blessing, mitzvah, kohen-priest, shacharis-morning-prayer, levites-leviyim

As answers to [Why don't we thank God for making us men/women?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/36902/why-dont-we-thank-god-for-making-us-men-women?lq=1) say, men thank Hashem for not making them a woman because the obligations or mitzvot that a man has is greater in number than that of a woman, slave, or non Jew.

However, why don't certain classifications of Jews (i.e. Kohanim or Leviim) make a declaration of their own highlighting the preponderance of mitzvot they have over regular Israelites?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36902/501 "Why don't we thank God for making us men/women?"

Comment: Leviyim dont have pidyon haben or peter chamor.

Answer (score 7):

Your question is referred to in the review [Beis Hillel כסלו תשס''ה](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?sits=1&req=50557&st=+%u05de%u05d3%u05d5%u05e2+%u05db%u05d4%u05df+) under the title “Why does not a kohen make a blessing שעשני כהן".

Rav Asher Anshil Schwarz asked the question and offered several answers. Relevant to your question is:

From the Mogein Shaul

> He also cannot make the blessing “שלא עשני ישראל ” because a kohen is
>   included in the designation  ישראל. Further, he would be glorifying
>   himself in the shame of his friend because until the sin of the golden
>   calf, the temple service would have been in the hands of the
>   Israelites.

Comment: Right I think the first point makes sense. But with regard to the second point why isn't that trepidation taken into account in regards to women.

Comment: @armoose You mean because of Chava? I wonder if women would still be exempt from many mitzvot had chava not sinner. I tend to doubt that